# Is there a way to add vertical padding to a custom scrollbar-thumb?

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

Considering scrollbar design on the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way that pictured scrollbar-thumb position would be a start of the scroll?

*So, one of the incomplete solutions I found is setting border-top to `{some_number}px solid white`, but in this case rounded corners are lost.
Making container of the scrollbar smaller is also not an option because in this case on small height screens additional scrollbar appears to scroll the container of the scrollbar container.*

Comment: What do you excatly want?

Comment: @KunalRaut That the scrolling up would be impossible (like it's top of scroll) considering picture attached.

Comment: @KunalRaut So there should be some top and bottom margins for the scrollbar.

Comment: Can you share your code on some live editor?

Comment: And it cannot happen this way until and unless there's some space left up there.